# Чтение файлов по ftp с помощью Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, ftp

По FTP доступны pdf файлы, которые время от времени поступают в определённую папку, и нужно постоянно проверять, нет ли новых файлов, и отправлять их запросом на другой сервер.

С отправкой проблем нет, но как мне получать их по FTP в автоматическом режиме, и отправленные файлы перемещать, например, в папку 'processed'? (

Узнал что можно сделать это через Spring Integration, но не смог разобраться в этой теме (нашел близкий к этому пример, но завести тоже не вышло https://dzone.com/articles/spring-integration-sftp-download-using-key-based-a).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это автоматизировать с помощью отдельной программы [WINSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php), он будет сохранять файлы в опредленной папке, а приложением перемещайте файлы куда угодно.

Winscp запомнит какие файлы он уже скачал.

Comment: Если нужно чисто через приложение, то извините.

Comment: Прилагаю ссылку на пример к программе Winscp, который подходит к Вашему случаю.
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_remember_downloaded_files